# How a non-prod BU affects a Prod BU on reputation/metrics terms?

Tags: marketing-cloud, performance, sfmc-business-unit, reputation

I received a request from a PO to explain her about how a test could affect the reputation or metrics.

I explained that for SFMC probably there's no differences among Business Units (BU) but in terms of performance it has too, but not sure.

My question is if there's any reputation affection from 1 BU to another? If there's any limit on the testing amount of emails sent or SMS?

I know reputation could be affected from a bad email/sms practices like not validate the domain or massive sending for marketing purposes...

I know about the transactional/commercial types of emails. What if both are mixed in both BU?

Answer (score 2):

This is your best reference: '[Sender Reputation Overview and Best Practices for Marketing Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314902&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)'

> Sender Reputation is usually based on the sender's IP address, but domain reputation is tracked by some ISPs (ISPs plan on more domain-based measures in future).

So if the child BU is using the same IP and domain they will affect reputation for sure.

Comment: Super pretty basic list, but thanks for the contribution.

Comment: Thanks both, the answers were pretty accurate for what I was looking for. I would love to share the answer acceptation and split into 2 parts!

Answer (score 2):

The reputation is not per BU - it is per IP and domain.

So if you use the same IP and Domain across all your BUs, if there is one bad apple, your entire batch is ruined.

As SFMC does not have a 'non-prod' option really (other than in very limited situations via a Sandbox edition) then in the eyes of SFMC and in all receiving ISPs and email clients, what you send from your designated 'test' BU and your PROD BU are identical - meaning if your test BU gets flagged as spam, so will your PROD BU.

Comment: Thanks both, the answers were pretty accurate for what I was looking for. I would love to share the answer acceptation and split into 2 parts!